# How to install matplotlib in python3.7?

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.7

I have error

```
No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt install python3.7 matplotlib
sudo apt install python3.7-matplotlib
pip install python3.7-matplotlib
```

result:

```
No matching distribution found for python3.7-matplotlib
```

Thank you.

Comment: The recommended way to install matplotlib (under the condition that you have python 3.7 installed already) is `python -mpip install matplotlib`.

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-X4eV03/matplotlib

Comment: Setuptools might be outdated. Try `python -mpip install --upgrade setuptools` first

Comment: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Operace zamítnuta: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Why is there python2.7? I dindn't install it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pip3.7 install matplotlib
```

Comment: - save this on your computer [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
- Navigate to download folder
- run `sudo python3.7 get-pip.py`
- After installation please run the pip3.7 command

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`